# Can't upgrade after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.4 to 22.04, insufficient disk space error

Tags: 22.04, disk-usage

This is my first upgrade operation after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. But, while trying to upgrade I get the following error message -

```
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

I went to the directory, it had many .deb files. I deleted them using -

```
sudo rm -rf *
```

But the error still persists.

This is my disk space analysis output -

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.4G  2.7M  1.4G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5  393G  373G  342M 100% /
tmpfs           6.8G  142M  6.7G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           6.8G     0  6.8G   0% /run/qemu
/dev/nvme0n1p1   96M   33M   64M  34% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.4G  4.1M  1.4G   1% /run/user/1000
```

My `/dev/` directory is like this -

```
autofs           drm_dp_aux0  i2c-0    loop0   loop21  loop34  loop-control      nvme0      rfkill    tty0   tty21  tty34  tty47  tty6       ttyS13  ttyS26   uhid        vcs4   vcsu4
block            ecryptfs     i2c-1    loop1   loop22  loop35  mapper            nvme0n1    rtc       tty1   tty22  tty35  tty48  tty60      ttyS14  ttyS27   uinput      vcs5   vcsu5
bsg              fb0          i2c-2    loop10  loop23  loop36  mcelog            nvme0n1p1  rtc0      tty10  tty23  tty36  tty49  tty61      ttyS15  ttyS28   urandom     vcs6   vcsu6
btrfs-control    fd           i2c-3    loop11  loop24  loop37  media0            nvme0n1p2  sda       tty11  tty24  tty37  tty5   tty62      ttyS16  ttyS29   usb         vcsa   vfio
bus              full         i2c-4    loop12  loop25  loop38  mem               nvme0n1p3  sg0       tty12  tty25  tty38  tty50  tty63      ttyS17  ttyS3    userio      vcsa1  vga_arbiter
char             fuse         i2c-5    loop13  loop26  loop39  mqueue            nvme0n1p4  shm       tty13  tty26  tty39  tty51  tty7       ttyS18  ttyS30   v4l         vcsa2  vhci
console          gpiochip0    i2c-6    loop14  loop27  loop4   net               nvme0n1p5  snapshot  tty14  tty27  tty4   tty52  tty8       ttyS19  ttyS31   vboxdrv     vcsa3  vhost-net
core             hidraw0      i2c-7    loop15  loop28  loop40  ng0n1             nvram      snd       tty15  tty28  tty40  tty53  tty9       ttyS2   ttyS4    vboxdrvu    vcsa4  vhost-vsock
cpu              hidraw1      initctl  loop16  loop29  loop41  null              port       stderr    tty16  tty29  tty41  tty54  ttyprintk  ttyS20  ttyS5    vboxnetctl  vcsa5  video0
cpu_dma_latency  hidraw2      input    loop17  loop3   loop5   nvidia0           ppp        stdin     tty17  tty3   tty42  tty55  ttyS0      ttyS21  ttyS6    vboxusb     vcsa6  video1
cuse             hidraw3      kfd      loop18  loop30  loop6   nvidiactl         psaux      stdout    tty18  tty30  tty43  tty56  ttyS1      ttyS22  ttyS7    vcs         vcsu   zero
disk             hpet         kmsg     loop19  loop31  loop7   nvidia-modeset    ptmx       tpm0      tty19  tty31  tty44  tty57  ttyS10     ttyS23  ttyS8    vcs1        vcsu1  zfs
dma_heap         hugepages    kvm      loop2   loop32  loop8   nvidia-uvm        pts        tpmrm0    tty2   tty32  tty45  tty58  ttyS11     ttyS24  ttyS9    vcs2        vcsu2
dri              hwrng        log      loop20  loop33  loop9   nvidia-uvm-tools  random     tty       tty20  tty33  tty46  tty59  ttyS12     ttyS25  udmabuf  vcs3        vcsu3
```

So which files can I safely delete?

Comment: Your root file system is still 100% full. You need to free up space somewhere else. Its capacity is close to ~400GB. Surely you have some large files you can relocate?

Comment: well can I expand root memory as my net disk space for Ubuntu is somewhere around 400 GB

Comment: @Nmath updated my question

Comment: The Ubuntu OS typically occupies no more than 40GB. So you have over 300GB you can delete...when you locate it. Removing packages and system files is seldom worthwhile -- they are small. Look for big data files, old downloads, movies, ancient backups, forgotten experiments, runaway logs. and other easier targets.

Comment: @user535733 I have an app installed, It constantly backs up all my system files since the beginning of the installation. Maybe after an Ubuntu upgrade, it has backed up my previous UBuntu system files, so that if I want I can go back to previous Ubuntu whenever I want. Then how to delete timeshift files?

Comment: If you open the TimeShift GUI select a snapshot you don’t need and click the delete button

Comment: Deleting a few timeshift snapshots solved my problem, thank you

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an external hard drive.  I've deleted more than half the files that were on the but it still shows completely full

Comment: @HenryM  Have you emptied the trash?